# How to replace these type-specific methods with a single method that uses Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to replace these type-specific `save` methods with a generic approach:

```
public Apple save(Apple apple)
{
    pm.makePersistent(apple);
    pm.close();
    return apple;
}

public Orange save(Orange orange)
{
    pm.makePersistent(orange);
    pm.close();
    return orange;
}
```

This is what I've come up with but I'm having trouble figuring out how to cast the return value:

```
public <T> T save(Object fruit, Class<T> model)
{
    pm.makePersistent(fruit);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public <T> T save(T fruit)
{
    pm.makePersistent(fruit);
    pm.close();
    return fruit;
}
```

Just copying what you've done earlier , that should work. You probably don't even need the Class parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need generics?

Why do you need to return the fruit? The invoker of the method already has a reference to the fruit object.

```
public void save ( Fruit fruit )
{
     pm.makePersistent(fruit);
     pm.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a need for generics with the above example?

```
public <T extends Fruit> T save(T fruit) {
    pm.makePersistent(fruit);
    pm.close();
    return fruit; //Is this needed?
}
```

The above will do it for you but if the `makePersistent()` method takes any type of fruit anyway there's really no need in this example.

Of course, if the real use case is somewhat different you may need it.

Comment: The above assumes the makePersistent method takes any type of fruit but gives it any type of Object.  It will not work.  Consider:  String s = "Hello World" ; String t = save ( s ) ;

Comment: @emory looking at the example I was actually assuming it did take any type of object, but I've altered the example to just take fruit now.